# IBOutlets deallocated after modal view controller

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, modalviewcontroller, iboutlet

I have a couple of IBOutlets in my ViewController class, declared like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel* labelHostStatus;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIButton* connectButton;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* fieldAddress;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField* fieldPort;
```

(and of course `@synthesize`'d)

Everything is working great, and I can access the IBOutlets in code, and get/set texts and stuff.

At some point I decide to present a modal view controller, which goes OK. However, after dismissing the modal view controller and coming back to the main controller, I can't seem to access the above mentioned outlets anymore. I get excepctions and crashes when trying to do so:

```
2013-05-13 22:39:47.359 [7267:c07] -[__NSCFString text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x885aa30
```

Whats wrong? :(

Comment: Could you share additional details? It's quite difficult to isolate the problem...

Comment: why are you strongly retaining your IBOutlet properties? those should be weakly retained

Answer (score 0):

Oh my, nevermind. Just figured I've released the parent view in the modal view controller class after it's been dismissed. D'oh!